# NA in textbox following DLOOKUP

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a dlookup to display some table content in a textbox but its returning #NA

For example: I have a table with 2 columns called USER1 & Total Calls Answered, and the table is called hourly1

My Dlookup is:

```
 =DLookUp("[Total Calls Answered]","[Hourly1]","[userid] = [USER1]")
```

Why is my textbox showing #NA

Comment: `USER1` or `userid` (as well as Sergeys answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the table `[Hourly1]` has only two fields, it means that it has no field `[CDP1]`. If this is the name of control of your form, use this for numeric CDP1:

```
=DLookUp("[Total Calls Answered]","[Hourly1]","[userid] = " & [CDP1])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I use your expression I get the following error: = #Name? instead of #NA

Comment: That'll be because `CDP1` isn't a control on a form... try changing it to `[User1]` as you have on your OP.  Or confirm that it is a control on a form?

Comment: What was the final `DLookUp` if Sergeys gave a #Name error?